# ¿ Cómo Mantener versiones diferentes de PHP en subdominios separados?

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, control-de-versiones

quiero subir un proyecto laravel a un hosting (hostinger) pero hostinger está configurado a PHP 7.3 ya que hay otro proyecto de PHP puro en ese hosting, con ese PHP 7.3, lo que pasa es que mi proyecto es laravel y tiene una versión actual,  al momento de actualizar el php del hosting a la versión actual, el proyecto de PHP puro deja de funcionar. Tener en cuenta que ambos proyectos son subdominios son subdominios me pueden dar opciones y/o soluciones. No sé si hay una forma para que el subdominio pueda tener una versión de php independiente de la versión que tenga el dominio

Comment: Hay posibilidades, pero dependen del sistema operativo, el servidor web, y el método de integración con PHP; incluso podrían ser relevantes las versiones.

Comment: ¿ En qué depende todo lo que me dijiste?

Comment: utiliza contenedores y diferentes puertos dentro de una misma vps

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Depende de **¿cuál?** sistema operativo, de **¿cuál?** servidor web y de **¿cuál?** método de integración con PHP. Incluso de **¿cuáles?** versiones.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que contratar otro plan de hosting y puedes perfectamente apuntar cada subdominio a cada host diferente y tener configurado una versión diferente de PHP en cada uno.
Pero mantener dos versiones de PHP en el mismo plan de hosting no es posible.

Comment: ¿ Digamos que no tengo esa opción, como podría hacer que esa versión antigua pueda ser compatible con las versiones actuales ?, es decir no creo que cada vez que yo suba un proyecto nuevo tenga que eliminar o volver hacer el proyecto anterior solo por su versión, me imagino que debe de haber una forma para subir un proyecto sea cual sea su versión

Comment: Para hacer que tu código antiguo sea compatible con las nuevas versiones de PHP debes actualizarlo manualmente corrigiendo los problemas, y para que tu código no quede obsoleto es buena idea aplicar siempre buenos principios a la hora de programarlo y usar arquitecturas limpias para que incluso en el caso de actualizaciones fuertes de PHP que cambien muchas cosas tu código pueda ser fácilmente actualizable.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).